# How do I handle this error as I don't know where to reference the video or where to call the video view

Tags: react-native, virtual-reality

Please, what could have been the problem? I am working on react-native 360 VR and walking through a sample I saw on the github but it is not working.

```
Invariant Violation: requireNativeComponent: "Video" was not found in the UIManager.
```

This error is located at:

```
in Video (at GVRVideo.js:13)
in VideoView (at App.js:20)
in RCTView (at View.js:45)
in View (at App.js:19)
in App (at renderApplication.js:34)
in RCTView (at View.js:45)
in View (at AppContainer.js:98)
in RCTView (at View.js:45)
in View (at AppContainer.js:115)
in AppContainer (at renderApplication.js:33)
```

"

I have GVRVideo.js,  GVRPanarama.js, and App.js

In my GVRVideo.js: I have the following code for the GVRVideo in components folder

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import { requireNativeComponent } from 'react-native'

class VideoView extends Component {
  render() {
    return <RCTViedoView {...this.props} />
  }
}

VideoView.propTypes = {
  video: PropTypes.shape({
    uri: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
    type: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
  }).isRequired,
  videoType: PropTypes.string,
  volume: PropTypes.number,
  displayMode: PropTypes.string,
  enableFullscreenButton: PropTypes.bool,
  enableCardboardButton: PropTypes.bool,
  enableInfoButton: PropTypes.bool,
  enableTouchTracking: PropTypes.bool,
  hidesTransitionView: PropTypes.bool,
}

// requireNativeComponent automatically resolves this to "VideoManager"
var RCTViedoView = requireNativeComponent('Video', VideoView);
export default VideoView;
```

In GVRPanarama.js: I have this file also in the components folder

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import { requireNativeComponent, Image } from 'react-native'


class PanoramaView extends Component {
  render() {
    return <RCTPanoramaView {...this.props} />
  }
}

PanoramaView.propTypes = {
  image: Image.propTypes.source,
  imageUrl: PropTypes.string,
  displayMode: PropTypes.string,
  enableFullscreenButton: PropTypes.bool,
  enableCardboardButton: PropTypes.bool,
  enableInfoButton: PropTypes.bool,
  enableTouchTracking: PropTypes.bool,
  hidesTransitionView: PropTypes.bool,
}

// requireNativeComponent automatically resolves this to "PanoramaManager"
var RCTPanoramaView = requireNativeComponent('Panorama', PanoramaView);
export default PanoramaView;
```

App.js:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, View} from 'react-native';

import GVRVideo from './components/GVRVideo';



export default class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <GVRVideo />
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: It sounds like a linking issue or there are some parts of the native modules not exposed to JavaScript correctly

Comment: Please can you help to point out

Comment: what kind of device are you using Android or iOS?

Comment: I am running on iOS

Comment: Any help please

Comment: `// requireNativeComponent automatically resolves this to "VideoManager"` What does that mean?

Comment: It would be more helpful, if you point us to the sample you are referring to.

Comment: I got the solution here https://github.com/tiero/react-native-360 and I followed it as described but it is showing errors which I don't even understand

Comment: It is unclear what you are trying to do here. Are you trying to install the package?

Comment: I am trying to display video-360, following the code sample I referenced above, it displayed error and that is why I am looking for help to fix it

Comment: By sample do you mean the `npm` package? For displaying 360 video you can make use of the package directly. You don't have to make use of the native components with `requireNativeComponent `. Have you installed using `npm install react-native-360 --save`?

Comment: I did that already and showing error. I have done the necessary but wondering why it is displaying error

Comment: That package works only for ios. I believe you are aware of that.

Comment: yes I am using IOS

Comment: Did you find any solution ?

Comment: No, I have not got a solution @udaybhaskar, I will appreciate if you can help